What does "porcelain sort of way." mean?
In Loving Vincent (2017), postman Joseph Roulin's son Armand speaks about painter Vincent:

Armand: He never did have much luck with women.
Boatman: You think? And, then he comes here with the Gachet girl.
Armand: I saw her pretty in a porcelain sort of way.
Boatman: That‘s her, a real quiet type.

What does "porcelain sort of way." mean ?

What do you suppose it might mean? What leads you to think so? What do dictionaries say about it? What have you done to find the answer for yourself? How has that failed to address your question adequately?

I expect there was a pause in Armand's speech. "I saw her - [she was] pretty in a porcelain sort of way."
Firms like Meissen have been making porcelain figurines like these for around 300 years. The girl must have had dainty features and a pink-and-white complexion like the typical female figurine.

Porcelain is usually considered pretty but fragile.
Pretty in a porcelain sort of way can be used to objectify and reduce a person to just a mere beauty. There's such a  negative connotation in what Armand said.
